# How can I create cartoon effect in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I can load image from gallery and save it, but in between, in edit portion,I want to learn to create cartonish effects in android studio, any comments will be helpful.

Comment: have you got any solution?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is third-party libraries that provide animation with build-in cartoon effects. Something like [here](https://mindorks.com/android/store/Animations/airbnb/lottie-android) is what you want, this should lead you on a path to find what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it now.

Comment: I looked in site, it provides cartoon animation fort buttons, I was hoping to apply that to face of someone